# Read and write multiple csv in a loop

Tags: r

I have 1000 files .dta in a folder :

```
C:/Folder/data1.dta
C:/Folder/data2.dta
C:/Folder/data" ".dta
C:/Folder/data1000.dta
```

I nead to apply a program to impute my 1000 data, and save this imputed data in a new folder.

```
C:/Folder2/data_new1.dta
C:/Folder2/data_new2.dta
C:/Folder2/data_new" ".dta
C:/Folder2/data_new1000.dta
```

I have built a complex programm with LEA package, to realize a completion with non-negative matrix factorization. It is work like that :

```
data1 <- read.dta("C:/Folder/data1.dta")

***********My program******

write.dta (data1, "C:/Folder/data_new1.dta")
```

I search a method to loop this for my 1000 datasets. With Stata, i can do like that :

```
forvalues i=1/1000 {

data`i' <- read.dta("C:/Folder/data`i'.dta")

***********My program******

write.dta (data`i', "C:/Folder/data_new`i'.dta")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a list:

```
f <- dir(pattern = "dta")
dat <- lapply(f, read.dta)
# do stuff to every data.frame
for (i in seq_along(dat)) {
  write.dta(dat[[i]], paste0("data_new", i, ".dta"))
}
```

Comment: The "do stuff to every data frame" and the write.dta could both be included inside `lapply`, with no need to actually save the list to an object.